# How to parse this type of JSON Response in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am new in iOS. I want to parse that type of JSON response in iOS. It's a PayPal response. I want to access all data and make to dictionary and store it for another purpose. How can i access all fields and make it dictionary?

```
{

    client =     {

        environment = sandbox;

        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.0.1";

        platform = iOS;

        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";

    };

    response =     {

        "create_time" = "2014-04-12T05:15:25Z";

        id = "PAY-72670124ZX823130UKNEMX3I";

        intent = sale;

        state = approved;

    };

    "response_type" = payment;

}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you parse it by transforming the JSON into an NSDictionary or an Object of your choice. But it seems like you didn't even google the issue...
try http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON using [`JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData%3aoptions%3aerror%3a)

```
NSData *data = responseData; // Data from HTTP response
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

if (!dictionary) {
    // An error occured - examine 'error'
}

NSString *responseType = dictionary[@"response_type"]; // Will extract "payment" out of the JSON
NSDictionary *client = dictionary[@"client"];
NSDictionary *response = dictionary[@"response"];
NSString *paypalSDKVerion = client[@"paypal_sdk_version"];
```

Comment: You left out error checking.

Comment: @Rich.Paypal response is NSdictionary JSON format.So,it's necessary to Parse using NSJSon?

Comment: There is no `NSDictionary` JSON format, JSON is always in the [standard format](http://www.json.org/) - so yep its necessary! :)

Comment: @RiCH.My question is Paypal give me dictionary of Response.It's default Convert data to dictionary.so, i can directly Access dictionary?

Comment: @user3528976 Yes, if Paypals SDK returns a `NSDictionary` you only need the last line.

Comment: @Rich Thanx for ur Replay.How can i access Inner data like Client Field into i want access all data and make it separate Dictionary.like environment,paypal_sdk_version and all field.

Comment: @user3528976 I've updated my answer. Hopefully you can see that there's a standard way of doing it :)